# build dict of class method attributes in python

Tags: python

I am trying to organize functions within a class into groups. I decided to add an attribute to each function within the class with a record that sets an attribute value. I want to have a dict made, maybe when the class is called, that will have the keys be the attribute I set, and the value be the method.  Here is a sample of the code:

```
def orientation(lr):
    def decorator(f):
        f.orientation = lr
        return f
    return decorator

def level(lr):
    def decorator(f):
        f.level = lr
        return f
    return decorator

class Artwork(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.groups = {}

    def __call__(self):
        pass

    @level('good')
    @orientation(RIGHT)
    def build_one(self):
        return """ some stuff """

    @level('bad')
    @orientation(RIGHT)
    def build_two(self):
        return """ some stuff """

   @level('bad')
    @orientation(RIGHT)
    def build_three(self):
        return """ some stuff """
```

It'd be great if something like this would be returned:

```
test = Artwork()
test.groups 
>> {'good': [build_one], 'bad': [build_two, build_three]}
```

I've tried to use reflection to loop through the class and look for attributes with hasattr but I can't seem to get it working.

## UPDATE:

I have another class Art which inherits Artwork.  It is in the Art class where I want to call a random function from within a 'group'. Currently I manually set which functions to use but I am trying to make it more robust by having groups of functions that I can randomly call based on some initial condition.

```
class Art(Artwork, object):

    """ Here is where instead of setting the available_art manually,
I will use the dict of groups of art functions.  
i.e. {'bad': [func1, func2], 'good': [func3, func5, func6]} """
def __init__(self, text, score):
    self.text = text
    self.available_art = [self.build_one,
                          self.build_two,
                          self.build_three,
                          self.build_four]
    self.score = score

def _decide_rank(self):
    total = functools.reduce(operator.add, self.score.values())
    passing = self.score.get('passing')
    percentage = (passing / total) * 100
    rank = SCORE_MAP[percentage] if percentage in SCORE_MAP else SCORE_MAP[min(SCORE_MAP.keys(), key=lambda k: abs(k-percentage))]
    return rank

def _get_longest_line(self, text):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    return len(max(lines, key=len))

def _build_bubble(self, text, spaces, orientation, length=40):
    bubble = []
    right = True if orientation == 'right' else False
    lines = self._normalize_text(text, length)
    bordersize = len(lines[0])

    rline = ' ' * spaces + '  ' + '-' * bordersize
    lline = '   ' + '-' * bordersize
    plines = rline if right else lline

    bubble.append(plines)

    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        border = self._get_border(lines, index, spaces, right)
        bubble.append('%s %s %s' % (border[0], line, border[1]))

    bubble.append(plines)

    return '\n'.join(bubble)

def _normalize_text(self, text, length):
    lines  = textwrap.wrap(text, length)
    maxlen = len(max(lines, key=len))
    return [line.ljust(maxlen) for line in lines]

def _get_border(self, lines, index, spaces, right):
    if len(lines) < 2:
        return [' ' * spaces + '<', '>'] if right else [' ' + '<', '>']
    elif index == 0:
        return [' ' * spaces + '/', '\\'] if right else ['/', '\\']
    elif index == len(lines) - 1:
        return [' ' * spaces + '\\', '/'] if right else ['\\', '/']
    else:
        return [' ' * spaces + '|', '|'] if right else ['|', '|']

def _randomizer(self):
    return random.randrange(0, len(self.available_art))

def build(self):
    pic = self.available_art[self._randomizer()]
    spaces = self._get_longest_line(pic())
    orientation = pic.orientation
    print self._build_bubble(self.text, spaces, orientation) + pic()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the methods using `dir()`, like this:

```
Artwork.groups = {}
for attr in dir(Artwork):
    try:
        v = getattr(Artwork, attr).level
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # level-less
    else:
        Artwork.groups.setdefault(v, []).append(attr)
```

Now both of these forms work, becase `groups` is set at the class level (you just need to get rid of the `self.groups = {}` line, because it hides the class-level member):

```
Artwork.groups
=> {'bad': ['build_three', 'build_two'], 'good': ['build_one']}
Artwork().groups
=> {'bad': ['build_three', 'build_two'], 'good': ['build_one']}
```

Using `dir` is better than accessing `Artwork.__dict__` directly, becaue this also supports inheritence (assuming you *do* want subclasses to inherit the levels of their superclasses)

UPDATE

If you need to apply this to multiple classes, make it a function:

```
def add_groups(cls):
  cls.groups = {}
  for attr in dir(cls):
    try:
        v = getattr(cls, attr).level
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # level-less
    else:
        cls.groups.setdefault(v, []).append(attr)
```

Then apply it:

```
add_groups(Artwork)
add_groups(Art)
```

Or, if you prefer, you can use a class-decorator.

Comment: I use have another class Art which inherits Artwork. Inside that Art class I call a random function from a statically built list.  What I want to do is call a random function from a certain group of functions - i.e., from 'good'.  That is why I had self.groups = {}

Comment: still, you don't need to set it at the instance level, you can use the class level attribute.

Comment: How would I do that within the Artwork Class?  I tried to add Artwork.groups = {} within Artwork and I get an error that Artwork is not defined.

Comment: Please update your question with more details about your inheritence structure, because it seems that it's missing relevant information.

Comment: If I understand your question, you can use the exact same approach on your class `Art` instead of `Artwork` (and any other class of interest), and then access it as `self.groups` from withing methods of `Art`. You don't need to assign `self.groups = ...`, since it is already defined at the class level.